# Changing Color of text in Java

Tags: java, swing, colors, jlabel

I am trying to create a separate `CustomFont` class in which I can different attributes of text. So I created a new class extended `Font` and inside created a private class Drawing which extends `JComponent`. I change the color and other characteristics of font and text inside `paintComponent` method.

The problem is `paintComponent` method is not getting called. I am sure I am making some mistake.

Here is the code:

```java
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class CustomFont extends Font {
    private String string;
    private int FontStyle;

    public CustomFont(String text, int style) {
        super("Serif", style, 15);
        FontStyle = style;
        string = text;  

        Drawing draw = new Drawing();
        draw.repaint();
    }

    private class Drawing extends JComponent {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15);
            g.setFont(font);
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.drawString(string, getX(), getY());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (Unrelated, but consider using Java naming conventions for variables, e.g., `FontStyle` would be `fontStyle`.)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: +1 to @AndrewThompson  and DaveNewton comments, this is not an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) as I have no idea how you are using his class, but see my answer below for some help.

Comment: txt_xxxx.setForeground(Color.red);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to my comment:

1) You dont honor the paint chain by calling `super.XXX` implementation of `paintComponent(..)` method which you should and it should be the first call in the overridden method or else anomalies could occur:

```
@Override 
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);

      Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15);
      g.setFont(font);
      g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
      g.drawString(string, 0, 0);
}
```

on the above code notice the `@Override` annotation so I am sure I am overriding the correct method. And also `getX()` and `getY()` has been replaced with 0,0, As `getX` and `getY` referred to the components position however when we call `drawString` we supply it with paramteres of where to draw within the container (and it must be within the bounds/size f container of course.

2) You should override `getPreferredSize` when drawing to graphics object and return `Dimension`s which fit your components drawings/contents or else visually there wont be anything visible as components size will be 0,0:

```
private class Drawing extends JComponent {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);//you would infact caluclate text size using FontMetrics#getStringWidth(String s)
    }
}
```

And just as a suggestion use some `RenderHints` and `Graphics2D` for nice looking text :) See here for more:

- [Displaying Antialiased Text by Using Rendering Hints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/renderinghints.html)

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot in this `CustomFont` class that doesn't really make any sense. For one, the lack of anything to actually do with a Font, for another the fact that you don't really use anything coded in it. The following would seem to be more along the lines of what you're looking for.

```
public class Drawing extends JComponent {
    String text;
    Font myFont;
    Color myTextColor;

    public Drawing(String textArg, Font f, Color textColor) {
        myFont = f;
        myTextColor = textColor;
        text = textArg;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setFont(myFont);
        g.setColor(myTextColor);
        g.drawString(text, 0, getHeight() / 2);
    }
}
```

To be used as shown below...

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15);
        String text = "blah blah blah";
        Color textColor = Color.YELLOW;
        Drawing d = new Drawing(text, font, textColor);

        frame.add(d);
        frame.setSize(100,100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Drawing makes use of a `Font`, a Font does not make use of a `Drawing`. It doesn't really make sense to have `Drawing` defined inside a `Font`.

Comment: For the first part, try draw.setSize(int w, int h) and see if that helps. You can also check if it has a non-zero size by printing draw.getSize() to the console.

For the second part, you don't want to use getX() and getY() in g.drawString(). drawString already draws relative to the position of the component. You need an x value between 0 and getWidth() and a y value between 0 and getHeight().

Comment: But I want to draw on the component and it can be something small so what then? How can I find it position without getX() and getY() if I want to draw on it

Comment: drawString draws on the component, regardless of where the component is on the screen. drawString(text, 0, 0) will draw in the top-left of the component no matter where the actual component is located.

Comment: Though you should note that the y coordinate for drawString(...) is where the BOTTOM of the text is. So if you drawString with a y-value of zero, the text will be outside the component. Try drawString(text, 0, getHeight()/2);

Comment: Now that I look this over, there are a few other things to clean up. Gimme a minute and I'll write out a new post.

Comment: P.S. is there a point to CustomFont? You defined it, but you never use any values from it except "string", which in itself, doesn't belong in a Font. A font describes the way of drawing a String, but doesn't contain a String to actually draw.